# How to change 9 digit uploaded data into 10-digit number in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am totally new to angular. I have angular UI where we upload a `.csv` file with 6 columns and their respective data, so before I invoke .net API, I need to change the data in the 1st column: if a value consists of 9 digits then we need to change it to 10 digits just by prefixing with ‘0’. For example, if the value is ‘609878837’ it has to be changed to ‘0609878837’.

**Sample Excel Data**

```
UserNumber      876876876               
DESCRIPTION     Hello               
AccountNumber   State   Current Premium Interest    Total
1207614641       FL         GG  200.51   24.58     225.09
 217614234       FL         GG  474.65   51.77     526.42
```

[Actual Excel sheet Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mynhP.png)

Here is my Angualr code which handles Upload and calls the .net API. Kindly let me know how do i change to 10 digits account numbers after checking the length

My Code:

```
<input #fileUpload type="file" class="file-upload" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" accept=".xlsx,.xls,.csv" required (change)="onFileChange($event)">
<button (click)="UploadFile(form.value)" type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!fileSelected">Upload</button>

onFileChange(event: any): void {
  this.file = event.target.files[0];

  if (this.file) {
    console.log("this.file.type: " + this.file.type);

    const fileName = this.file.name;

    this.fileSelected = true;
    this.invalidFileType = false;
    this.invalidFileSize = false;
    this.invalidFileRecords = false;
    let file: File = this.file;
    var value;
    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = (e: any) => {
      value = e.target.result;

      this.data = value;

      var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
      if (rows.length > 6003) {
        LoggerService.error(`upload records less than 6K.`, true, true);
      }

    };

    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(this.file);
  }
}
    
    
UploadFile(filevalue) {
  const reqbody = {
    filename: this.file?.name,
    destinationPath: '',
    lines: this.data.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9,\n\r.'" ]/g, "").split('\r\n')
  };

  var route = "CallNETAPI";
  this.dataService.post(reqbody, route).subscribe(
    (data: any[]) => {
      console.log("Response data: " + data);
      LoggerService.success(`File successfully uploaded to server`, true, false);
      this.responseData = data;
    },
    (error: Response) => {
      this.displayError = true;
      this.errorText = `Error from CallNETAPI API service ${error.status}`;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';


onFileChange(e): void {

  if(e.target.files[0]!=undefined){
    let ext = e.target.files[0].name.split('.').pop();
    const extList = ["csv","xlsx", "xls","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "application/vnd.ms-excel"];
    let isvalidExtension = extList.includes(ext.toLowerCase());;
    if (isvalidExtension) {

        /* wire up file reader */
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(e.target);
    if (target.files.length !== 1) throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      /* read workbook */
      const bstr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' , cellNF : true });
      
      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wb.SheetNames[0].toString()];

      /* save data */
      data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws , {
        header: 1,
        defval: "",
        raw:false
      });

      let data1 = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {raw:false});
      data.shift(); // to delete UserNumber column
      data.shift(); // to delete Description column
      data.shift(); // to remove data headers.
      
      if (data.length > 6000) {
        LoggerService.error(`upload records less than 6K.`, true, true);
      }

      data.forEach((element , index) => {
        element[0] = String(element[0]).padStart(10, '0'); // 0 as index for AccountNumber
      });

      console.log("Final Excel data as array" , data);
     
    };
  
  }
  else {
    alert('File type is not accepted - Please Upload Excel File');
  }
  }

 
}
```